# Navigation Controllers disappearing in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I currently have my app set up in a split view controller such that the details view and the master view both have navigation controllers, and the details view has recursive segues between it and another view.  I use show segues, so I would figure the navigation bar would stay on top of the presented detail views.  However, after activating both of the segues, the navigation bar disappears and I am left with what appears to be modal segues.

Below is a screenshot of my sample storyboard setup that reproduces the problem:

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5c8aqqpxho6whnj/SwiftSplitPizzaDemo-master.zip?dl=0)

Here is a link to the sample project:

Any suggestions for how I can keep the Navigation Bar at the top of the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push `ViewController` using of navigation controller like

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       buttonNext.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapsOnNext), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    func tapsOnNext(){
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController") as? NextViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
    }
```

& in `NextViewController` use

```
   buttonPrev.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapsOnNext), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    func tapsOnNext(){
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

[image: For Next ViewController]

[image: For PrevViewController]

Comment: I don't want to pop the next view controller.  When the buttons are pushed, I just want to keep adding them to the stack.  Similar to Twitter or Facebook, where you can view a user's profile, then click on another profile from there, and then yet another profile, and all of those are added to the view stack.

Comment: Then use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)` But careful about navigation stacks.

Comment: If you mean be careful about memory, my data is hardcoded and the most levels of recursion you'll get is 3.  I just wanted to reuse the storyboard view rather than making 3 dupes

Comment: As you mentioned in first comment (Need only three stack) then after that use pop viewcontroller, its fine, You can go ahead.